# How to know how many users click on the clustrmaps picture?

Tags: google-analytics

I have got a website with a ClustrMaps button (to check from where are coming the visitors).

I want to know how many times users click on that (I am using Google Universal Analytics).

Thanks in advance for your help and your time.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using an onClick function to fire off a GA event to track button clicks.  Google has a decent syntax example here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#Anatomy

Your onClick might look something like this:

```
onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'buttons', 'click', 'clustrmaps']);"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot.

So I added this line just after the "a href" of the HTML code of ClustrMaps.
I updated the footer file on my server and no errors, great.

But now, I guess that I need to create an event in Google Analytics interface, but I can't find where, please could you tell me where is this menu located?

Contents > Events > Overview?

EDIT : I found where to create an event (on the latest Google Analytics version) following this article :

http://www.blastam.com/blog/index.php/2011/03/how-to-use-events-goals-google-analytics/

I guess that I need to wait some hours until the event, because I maked a click right now and it stills 0 events.